# HTML5 Canvas - circle animation with image

Tags: html, animation, canvas

Im trying to get something like this --> http://jsfiddle.net/NhvAZ/10/ but with image inside circle.

I did exactly the same way like on example above, but it doesn't work with image. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/uyEaq/

Someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well the 1st example doesn't work in Chrome for a start...

Comment: @SpaceBeers Oops! I'm sorry. I tested on IE9 and Firefox and worked fine, so I was sure it will work in Chrome also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was really confusing, but looking at some of the previous iterations of the fiddles you've given I think I know what you want.

You want an ever increasing pie slice of an image to appear, right? Clipping can do that for you. Here's an example using some of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QMZg2/

Comment: Exactly! that's what I wanted. I'm sorry that I didn't say it clear.  Your example doesn't work in Firefox (lasted version). Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can't edit comment above. Looks like it works in Firefox. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Thanks a Lot Simon Sarris.
U saved My time